# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ 
I am getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<DirCert.Data.Model.DssClient_Sasid_Certified>`

I can't figure out how to solve this error.

Here is my code:

```
public List<DssClient_Sasid_Certified> GetCertifiedRecordsbySasid(string Sasid)
{
    return (from o in _context.DssClient_Sasid_Certified
            where (o.SasId == Sasid)
            join t in _context.DssClients on o.ClientId equals t.ClientId
            select new 
            {
                ClientId = o.ClientId,
                SasId = o.SasId,
                FormalLastName = o.FormalLastName,
                FormalFirstName  = o.FormalFirstName,
                FormalMiddleName = o.FormalMiddleName,
                BenefitSource = t.BenefitSource,
                DOB = o.DOB
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a list of anonymous type from a method? As  far as I know, this is prohibited.

Comment: Don't return anonymous types from methods but concrete types. So in this case  it would make sense to create a class `DssClient` and return a `List<DssClient>` or `IEnumerable<DssClient>`.

Comment: You are returning a `List<T>` where T is the anonymous type the compiler generates for your select, whereas you method expects a `List<DssClient_Sasid_Certified>`

Comment: You will have to either use a concrete type or return `List<object>` from your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select clause:

```
select new 
{
    ...
}
```

is selecting an anonymous type. You need it to select a `DssClient_Sasid_Certified`, so that you can return the type that your method declaration says you're going to return. You *may* just need to change your code to:

```
select new DssClient_Sasid_Certified
{
    ...
}
```

... assuming `DssClient_Sasid_Certified` has all the properties you're setting, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is supposed to be returning a List of DssClient_Sasid_Certified, but your linq query is creating an anon type.

You could do something like:

```
public List<DssClient_Sasid_Certified> GetCertifiedRecordsbySasid(string Sasid)
{

    return (from o in _context.DssClient_Sasid_Certified
            where (o.SasId == Sasid)
            join t in _context.DssClients
                     on o.ClientId equals t.ClientId
            select new DssClient_Sasid_Certified()
            {
                ClientId = o.ClientId,
                SasId = o.SasId,
                FormalLastName = o.FormalLastName,
                FormalFirstName  = o.FormalFirstName,
                FormalMiddleName = o.FormalMiddleName,
                BenefitSource = t.BenefitSource,
                DOB = o.DOB
            }).ToList();

}
```

This is of course assuming your object has a parameterless constructor for DssClient_Sasid_Certified, and that the properties you're using in your anon object are the same as your DssClient_Sasid_Certified

The line from your original query:

```
select new .....
```

Basically says, create me a new Anonymous type, which an anonymous type cannot be converted automagically to a non anonymous type (your list of DssClient_Sasid_Certified).

Read more about Anonymous types here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Error message states it clearly.Your return type is `List<DssClient_Sasid_Certified>` but you are trying to return a list of anonymous types.So the types do **not** match,they are not compatible. You need to create instances of your type instead of anonymous types:

```
select new DssClient_Sasid_Certified { .. }
```